# batch rename files on ftp server using mac terminal

Tags: macos, ftp, terminal

I have a simple question, how to rename files on an ftp server in a mac terminal?
if possible with a loop to rename all files at once.

i tried the mv command but this does not work on an ftp connection. how to change this command?

```
for i in *; do mv "$i" "$(echo $i|tr A-Z a-z)"; done
```

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either download and use an advanced FTP client such as [SmartFTP](http://www.smartftp.com/client/features/bulkrename) which offers such option to bulk rename files (but you need the paid version), or mount the connection using [this method](http://osxdaily.com/2011/02/07/ftp-from-mac/) and go to `/Volumes/the.ftp.server.com/` and run your command.

Comment: if i use the for loop command i get this message: mv: rename A.gif to a.gif: Read-only file system . do i need to do something more because it's a mounted volume?

Comment: i found it, with macfusion you can mount an ftp like a "real harddrive" and do all the operations needed. thx for the help

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar batch rename task to perform and I couldn't get macfusion to work on my mac.

Here's what I did:

1. Get wingfs and mount the ftp drive:
   http://www.wingfs.com/wingfs/
2. Get the perl rename utility so I can use regex's to rename in batch:

I followed these instructions:
http://digitalcardboard.com/blog/2009/09/15/linux-rename-utility-on-os-x/

Basically, get the rename perl script (https://github.com/nricklin/rename/blob/master/rename) and then you can run commands like

```
rename 's/ /_/;' *    # replace space with underscore
```